# A couple of errors in "Space Shooter" game

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

So I was working on this "Space Shooter" game and I came across a couple of bugs that was not making my game work properly/crashing.

So the first problem is that my game sometimes crashes when the function that I created is used in "didBeginContact" Here is the code in "didBeginContact"

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids)){

        asteroidsHitEachOther(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, FuriousAsteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids)){

        bulletHitAsteroids(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }
    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Bullet) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids)){

        bulletHitfAsteroids(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Asteroids)){

        fighterGetHit(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Asteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }


    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) || (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Fighter) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.fAsteroids)){

        fighterGetHitHard(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, fAsteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

  }
```

So the game sometimes crashes with these errors.
[Error #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzYvH.png)
[Error #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAtvZ.png)

The line that the game crashes with are these lines.

```
asteroidsHitEachOther(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, FuriousAsteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

bulletHitAsteroids(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

bulletHitfAsteroids(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

fighterGetHit(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Asteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

fighterGetHitHard(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, fAsteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
```

Now if you want to see the way I created my functions, then you can look here to see all the functions.

```
func asteroidsHitEachOther(Asteroids: SKSpriteNode, FuriousAsteroids: SKSpriteNode){

    Asteroids.removeFromParent()
    FuriousAsteroids.removeFromParent()

}

func bulletHitAsteroids(Asteroids: SKSpriteNode, Bullet: SKSpriteNode){

    Asteroids.removeFromParent()
    Bullet.removeFromParent()

    Points++
    pointLabel.text = "Points: \(Points)"

}

func bulletHitfAsteroids(fAsteroids: SKSpriteNode, Bullet: SKSpriteNode){

    fAsteroids.removeFromParent()
    Bullet.removeFromParent()

    Points = Points + 2
    pointLabel.text = "Points: \(Points)"

}

func fighterGetHit(Fighter: SKSpriteNode, Asteroids: SKSpriteNode){

    Asteroids.removeFromParent()


    HitPoints--
    hpLabel.text = "\(HitPoints) HP"

}

func fighterGetHitHard(Fighter: SKSpriteNode, fAsteroids: SKSpriteNode){

    fAsteroids.removeFromParent()

    HitPoints = HitPoints - 2
    hpLabel.text = "\(HitPoints) HP"

}
```

Now after we've talked about the first error, I'll be talking about the second error that doesn't work the game properly.

Now we can see that in the functions above, on the "bulletHitfAsteroids", the points variable is suppose to go up by two. But when I played the game, the points go up by only one when I hit the fAsteroids. This goes the same for "fighterGetHitHard", the health doesn't go down by two but instead goes down by only one.

I would appreciate the help I can get, thank you.

Comment: Haven't looked at hardly any of the code, but you don't check bitmasks using `==`.  Also all that `if (foo && bar) fooHitBar()` is so tedious and bloated.  Subclass your objects from a common base class and tell them they've hit something else and let them worry about it.

Comment: Then how am I suppose to chest bitmasks? And will it fix my problem?

Comment: @RapidReverse Those crashes probably comes from the fact that you are using as! which is forced downcasting. You should use as? because obviously, you are not sure if the node is actually instance of SKSpriteNode. Another part of the problem is your didBeginContact method, and how you handle it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195241/3402095) for more info.

Comment: @Whirlwind so when I changed the "as!" to "as?" It came with the error of "Value of Optional type 'SKSpriteNode?' not wrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: That is because for example, `firstNode.node` is an optional and it can be nil. You should use optional binding : `if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {methodThatAcceptsSKSpriteNode(sprite)}` I haven't really looked much into your code, but using forced unwrapping and forced downcasting like that, as you can see, can easily lead into crashes. Always try to access the underlying value of optionals in a safe way.

Comment: @Whirlwind So I tried adding `if let sprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {methodThatAcceptsSKSpriteNode(sprite)}` on to lines that crashes such as `fighterGetHitHard(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, fAsteroids: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)` but it still crashes. Am I putting it in the wrong place?

Comment: @Whirlwind Can you please answer my question? The bug is frustrating me.

Comment: @RapidReverse First of all, to handle the contacts use the code from the link I've posted. Right now, you are not handling it correctly. About crashes... Have you changed all forced downcasting (as!) to optional downcasting (as?). Also, when it crashes, where it crashes and what is the error message?

Comment: @Whirlwind I did change all the (as!) to (as?) but it came with this error "Value of optional type 'SKSpriteNode?' not wrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" and also I have posted the errors I received in the links above called **Error #1** and **Error #2**

Comment: @RapidReverse I've responded to that in my previous comments. You have to use optional binding when accessing optionals ...

Comment: @Whirlwind Also when I followed the code suggestion when changing from (as!) to (as?). The game works, **BUT** it still crashes, but with a different error. The error is "Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom" It also usually crashes on the same line that crashes with (as!) instead of (as?)

Comment: @RapidReverse You mean : `CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom` message?

Comment: @RapidReverse Well that is not a crash. It is just warning. You can search SO about it.

Comment: @Whirlwind Actually my bad. The error isn't in the console, but is in the code screen itself. The error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I368_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: @RapidReverse What line of code causes that ?

Comment: @Whirlwind it's the same lines under the quote "The line that the game crashes with are these lines." It "randomly" chooses a line to crash but I predict that there is a reason for the "random" pick.

Comment: @Whirlwind Hello? Are you like busy with other things and can't answer this question. 'Cause I would much appreciate if you or someone else could solve my problem.

Comment: @Whirlwind is there a "bump" option to make people see this question more?